# A question for square root in Handcalcs plugin for juputer notebook

Tags: python, plugins, latex

I have recently figured out a wonderful tool which renders equations in python to latex format. But there is a small problem that it always adds a bracket for square root which makes it look redundant.
Here is a part of my code

```
#%%

import math
import handcalcs.render

pi = math.pi
g = 9.8
uk1 = 0.281
s1 = 10.615
d2 = 4.1579

#%%

%%render
#Long

# a2: acceleration from position 1 to before collision

a2 = -uk1*g
s2 = math.sqrt(s1**2+2*a2+d2)
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: pic]

I wonder it there is any why to eliminate the brackets in the square root.
Thx alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of handcalcs.

Currently, there is not a voluntary way of removing the brackets. They are there simply because when using the `sqrt` function, there are brackets around the function's argument and they therefore appear in the rendered result. I agree, it would be nice to not have those outer brackets within the `sqrt` sign. If you are willing, please post this as a feature request on the Github page. I can start looking into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Btw I'm surprised that someone actaully did make it so easy to display function in latex format and handcalcs really helped me a lot for my project and presentation. It's my honor to use your product sir!! :D

Comment: Later ill post this problem to the Github page

Comment: That's great to hear. Thanks for sharing that! Also, update to handcalcs v.0.8.1 and you will no longer have brackets under the radical sign. However, if the radical sign is in a fraction, then there will still be brackets.

Comment: Great work sir! I will go get the update right now.